# Asio C++ Library: asio/detail/config.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, boost-asio, qmake

I downloaded the latest standalone version of [Boost's Asio Library](http://think-async.com/Asio/Download). Now I would like to integrate the header-only library in a simple qt creator c++ project. But if i try to run the "hello world" example with asio.hpp included I get the following error message (see below for full error message):

```
asio/detail/config.hpp: No such file or directory
```

These are the steps i took so far

1. created a new project (c++ with qmake) in qt creator
2. extracted the asio library
3. copied the include and src folder of asio into a "libs" directory in my project
4. specified in the .pro file that c++11 should be used by

   CONFIG += c++11
5. moreover i tried to add the following defines in my main:

> ```
>  #define ASIO_STANDALONE
>  #define ASIO_HAS_STD_ADDRESSOF
>  #define ASIO_HAS_STD_ARRAY
>  #define ASIO_HAS_CSTDINT
>  #define ASIO_HAS_STD_SHARED_PTR
>  #define ASIO_HAS_STD_TYPE_TRAITS
>
>  #include <iostream>
>  #include "libs/asio/include/asio.hpp"
>
>  using namespace std;
>
>  int main()
>  {
>      cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
>      return 0;
>  }
> ```

6. It seems that qmake does not know about all includes. I'm not very fimilar with cmake, qmake and this stuff. So as a noob I tried to add a new INCLUDEPATH in the .pro file ...

   INCLUDEPATH += ./libs/asio/include

...and got a new error:

```
boost/detail/atomic_count.hpp: No such file or directory
```

This is the complete error message for my first error:

```
make: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/asiotest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release'
/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -spec /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o Makefile ../asiotest/asiotest.pro
make: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/asiotest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release'
make: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/asiotest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release'
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../asiotest -I../asiotest -I. -o main.o ../asiotest/main.cpp
In file included from ../asiotest/libs/asio/include/asio.hpp:18:0,
                 from ../asiotest/main.cpp:9:
../asiotest/libs/asio/include/asio/async_result.hpp:18:34: fatal error: asio/detail/config.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/asiotest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release'
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
17:55:01: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project asiotest (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

the file hierarchie:

```
asiotest (project folder)
-- asiotest.pro
-- sources (folder)
---- main.cpp
-- libs (folder)
---- asio (folder)
------- include(folder)
---------- asio.hpp 
---------- asio (folder)
------------- detail (folder)
------------- more folders
------- src
---------- asio.cpp
---------- asio_ssl.cpp
```

**How can I teach qt to search for the include files in the right directory?**

Note: Sorry for the quote around the source code but i didn't managed to get the code highlighted in the numbered list by simple using the source code "tag".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpfull for future visitors of this question. I managed to solve the problem. I even got the http server example of asio running. Meanwhile is also switched from ubuntu to debian and from qmake to cmake but i don't think that this was the reason in the end. The following CMakeLists.txt works for me:

```
project(asiotest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -DASIO_STANDALONE -pthread")
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
include_directories(asio/include)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

**Note the -pthread option**. I got a lot of linker errors without it. See also [here](https://github.com/RJ/libf2f/issues/1).
The folder structure is nearly the same as before:

```
asiotest (project folder)
-- [..source files of http server example..]
-- libs (folder)
---- asio (folder)
------- include(folder)
---------- asio.hpp 
---------- asio (folder)
------------- detail (folder)
------------- more folders
------- src
---------- asio.cpp
---------- asio_ssl.cpp
```